# Ruby on Rails function for model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one active record model called `Task` with following attributes:

- `name (string)`
- `due (date)`
- `priority (int)`

How do I create a function for priority so I can call it something like this

`@task.priority.to_str` would produce "Low", "High" based off the integer value

I don't want to override the attribute method to print out the string because I need to access the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new instance method:

```
class Task
  def str_priority
    priority < 5 ? 'Low' : 'High'
  end
end

@task.str_priority
```

Comment: is it possible to extend the attribute to have its own method just like it already has `to_s`

Comment: yes, but that will override for all its class type which is integer class in this case, and that is not recommended as you may have an integer like "this is a string and a number as well #{3}" and in this case will replace 3 with `Low` as you already override integer class and no one will expect that.

Comment: I ended up writing new method for the instance